# Storing text more than 32762 chars in BigSQL Hadoop external table

Tags: sql, db2, varchar, bigsql

I want to store a text of size 70000, but BigSQL Hadoop extrernal table restricts maximum field length to 32762. I do not want to trim or split into multiple columns. Is there any other datatype that let's me to load the full data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CLOB`

[String types in DB2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_stringdatatypes.html)

Comment: As you had mentioned CLOB can be used in actual tables. If I am looking to create external tables on top of Hadoop, it doesn't support CLOB. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @PariSairamMohan you should include that info in your question